# Contour plot of multivariate distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, distribution

I have a matrix of data (Xa.shape = 100x2) related to class A and another one for class B. I created both using the code below and I want to make a contour plot of the data. But what I tried doesn't work and just creates a blue picture. How do I create a proper contour plot of such data?

```
N = 1000

mean_a = [0, 0]
cov_a = [[1, 0], [0, 100]]  # diagonal covariance

mean_b = [5, 0]
cov_b = [[5, 0], [0, 500]]  # diagonal covariance

Xa = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_a, cov_a, N)
Xb = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_b, cov_b, N)
fig, ax3 = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,figsize=(15,8))
ax3.contourf(Xa)
```

Comment: I used `np.random.randn` to create some pseudo data for Xa and I do not have your problem. Would you mind posting some of your sample data?

Comment: @XiaoyuLu Ok, I will update the question, thanks.

Comment: Using your data and code above I successfully created the plot. Not sure what causes the problem.

Comment: @XiaoyuLu It doesn't have clear contours, in fact nothing can really be seen...

Comment: Have you tried to change the colormap (e.g. `ax3.contourf(Xa, cmap='inferno')`)?

Comment: @XiaoyuLu Doesn't really make much a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Input:** two-dimensional data points - `Xa` is of shape [N, 2]. These are N poins in 2D space.

**Desired output:** contour plot in two dimensions. `countourf` is the right tool for that, but take note of the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html). This function draws the contour of a *height map*.

**Missing step:** turning individual data points into a height map.

The question is about distributions. To plot a distribution in 1D we would generate a histogram. To do so in 2D, well.. let's create a 2D histogram! [`numpy.histogram2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) will do just that for us. It creates a height map suitable for `contourf` by dividing the space into regular bins and counting the number of data points that fall into each bin.

Here we go:

```
N = 1000

mean_a = [0, 0]
cov_a = [[2, 1], [1, 2]]

Xa = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_a, cov_a, N)
fig, ax3 = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,figsize=(15,8))

(counts, x_bins, y_bins) = np.histogram2d(Xa[:, 0], Xa[:, 1])
ax3.contourf(counts, extent=[x_bins[0], x_bins[-1], y_bins[0], y_bins[-1]])
```

[image]

Comment: One question - how can I display 2 distributions on the same plot, let's say Xa and Xb?

Comment: I don't know - what should the result look like?

Comment: What I ideally want to do is plot the contour lines of Xa and Xb on the same plot and then draw a vector in the optimal direction that maximizes the Fisher ratio.

Comment: You can repeat the same procedure for `Xb`, but then one set of contours would cover the other. Maybe drawing the second one transparently (by passing `alpha=[some value between 0 and 1]` to `contourf`) could work for you. Alternatively, draw unfilled contours with `contour`.